# send fax with C# and FAXCOMLIb

Tags: c#, fax, windows

I am working on a project to send 2 files with fax several times.
this is my code :

```
public static bool SendFax(string Recipient, string Number, params string[] Files)
{
    FaxServer server = new FaxServerClass();

    try
    {  
        server.Connect(Environment.MachineName);                    
        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
        {    
            FaxDoc faxDoc = (FaxDoc)server.CreateDocument(Files[i]);
            faxDoc.RecipientName = Recipient;
            faxDoc.FaxNumber = Number;                                                
            faxDoc.Send().ToString();    
        }    
        return true;    
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        server.Disconnect();
    }    
}
```

I have a grid, When user click on a button , i call this method for each row of grid. Problem is here , I want remove each row ,if fax set successfully , but how i can find out my fax sent correctly or not ?

thanks

**More Info** :

Working with VS 2010 , Windows App , C#

Comment: Use FAXCOMEXLib to get notifications, add a reference to c:\windows\system32\fxscomex.dll instead.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms689576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `faxDoc.Send()` fax is not sent immediately, but it is put into faxqueue instead. [Here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/insights/650334-how-find-status-fax-operation-using-faxcom-dll) is an article how you can check status of your fax message in a faxqueue (It is VB.NET, but you will have no problems converting it into C#). Call that method periodically until it is sent.